# how to display the field name from the corresponding class in the same field in Angular

Tags: angular

I develop my app and i want to display filed name of correct object in Angular.  I have a shopping list with objects that are of different classes and I want to display the name of the object in field on this list depending on what class this object is. 
my products can be cheese and meat classes and each such product has a name.
How can i do it?
I have sth like this but I don't know how to display it. When I put where the question mark is:
`basket.cheese.name` displays the specific name of the cheese. how to combine it in a situation where it is a meat class object to display the name of a particular meat?

```
<table class="table table-striped" aria-describedby="page-heading">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col"  ><span>ID</span> <fa-icon [icon]="'sort'"></fa-icon></th>
        <th scope="col"  ><span>Name of product</span> <fa-icon [icon]="'sort'"></fa-icon></th>

        <th scope="col"></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let basket of basketList">
        <td> {{basket.id}}</td>
        <td>{{?}}</td>


        <td class="text-right">

        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

UPDATE:

```
@Entity
public class Basket {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;


@ManyToOne
private Cheese cheese;
@ManyToOne
private Meat meat;
@ManyToOne
private User user;

public Basket() {
}

public Basket (Cheese cheese, Meat meat, User user) {

    this.articles = articles;
    this.conferences = conferences;
    this.user = user;
}
getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for one of your classes?

Comment: what exactly should I post? my code written in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off the information you gave. I assumed your Basket model might look something like this:

```
public basketList = [
    {
      id: '123',
      cheese: {
        name: 'Swiss'
      },
      meat: {
        name: 'Beef'
      }
    },
    {
      id: '456',
      cheese: {
        name: 'Provolone'
      }
    },
    {
      id: '789',
      meat: {
        name: 'Chicken'
      }
    },
  ];
```

In which case in your HTML, a potential solution you could use is something like this:

```
 <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let basket of basketList">
        <td>id: {{basket.id}}</td>
        <td *ngIf="basket?.meat">{{basket?.meat?.name}} </td>
        <td *ngIf="basket?.cheese">{{basket?.cheese?.name}} </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Working [StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ic7yf7)